# Email an admin 36 hours after a new user registers in WordPress

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, date, cron

Anyone here know or can give me a guidance on how to email a WordPress Admin 36 hours after a new user registers on their website?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Find all users in the database
2. Check if users have a specific role/roles
3. Check if some of these users have registered for 36 hours already
4. Use WP_cron to set these (I'll use every hour to be sure that I catch all these users)

Here is the code that I'm doing so far, but I'm always getting lost whenever I want to get the users that has registered for 36 hours.

```
/**


* SEND A NOTIFICATION AFTER 36 HOURS
 */

function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_hour'] = array(
        'interval' => 3600, // Every hour
        'display'  => __( 'Every hour' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'qd_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_hour', 'qd_cron_hook' );
}

///Hook into that action that'll fire every hour
 add_action( 'qd_cron_hook', 'qd_cron_function' );

//create function, that runs on cron
function qd_cron_function() {
    $args = array(
        'role'         => 'business-pending',
        'fields'       => array( 'ID', 'user_registered' ),
     );
    $users = get_users( $args );

    foreach($users as $user){
        $user_regDate = $user->user_registered;
        $dateNow = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

> This is where I get lost. I'm assuming that I have to subtract the time now to the user_registered value and then make a condition to only display users that has registered in 36 hours.

```
        $emailto = get_option('admin_email');
        $subject = 'Please activate this user';
        $message = 'This user has not been activated.';
        wp_mail( $emailto, $subject, $message );
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just do a regular MySQL query with condition of `user_registered` < now - 36hrs? Though 2 things to note of: 1. Don't sent mail in 2 each. 2. Mark users you've already sent email about or do the opposite, mark only new users (usermeta) and then remove that field during this cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174700/wp-user-query-users-by-registered-date

Where you have :

```
$args = array(
    'role'         => 'business-pending',
    'fields'       => array( 'ID', 'user_registered' ),
 );
$users = get_users( $args );
```

You can replace with:

```
$args = array(
    'role'         => 'business-pending',
    'fields'       => array( 'ID', 'user_registered' ),
    'date_query'    => array(
        array(
            'before'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." -36 hours")), // registered more than 36 hours ago
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
     ),
 );
$users = get_users( $args );
```

Suggestion:

Please be aware that with your code you'll be getting users registered more than 36 hours. Most probably you should use some flag in the database to signal which users emails were sent already.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I added a meta key that will check if the email has already been sent about this person. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again.